# Sharepoint to Alfresco datalist migration

Tags: sharepoint, migration, alfresco, datalist

I am working on sharepoint 2013 to Alfresco**(5.2.f)** migration project.

In sharepoint, any user can make datalists with their own set of columns from UI, we have around 4000 datalists available in sharepoint.
But in alfresco for datalists, we have to create custom type.

Each datalist may have mandatory property and user/document association also.

In alfresco, do we have any tool or any way using which we can make datalists more quickly. Content model manager tool doesn't provide parent type as dl:dataListItem.

For the datalist's data migration, do we have any freeware addon/tool or need to write custom one?

In case of custom one, what should be the approach using which we can accommodate mandatory properties and associated fields also?

Comment: Interesting question and I haven't found any freeware as of now and you required to write your own.

Answer (score 2):

The CMIS spec introduced the concept of Type Mutability, which allows new content types to be defined at run-time. Unfortunately, Alfresco does not support Type Mutability as far as I know.

You could generate Alfresco content model XML, check that into the repository programmatically, and then do a hot deploy of the model, but it's probably not the best idea because hot-deploying a bad model could be really problematic.

You could generate Alfresco content model XML and then package it as an AMP and deploy it like any other customization. You'll have to write that code yourself, and obviously, it has the downside of requiring a restart every time you add a new type. But it is the safest way to deploy content model changes.

Finally, something to think about is whether or not those data lists actually belong in Alfresco in the first place. Maybe a JSON document store would be a better place to store that data. With 4000 different types of lists it is obvious that your end users value being able to dynamically define types. Maybe you should use Alfresco for what it is good for--storing files and metadata about those files--and something with more flexible schemas like CouchDB or MongoDB for storing the data lists.

It is also worth noting that the new Alfresco Digital Workspace (aka Content App) doesn't have an interface for editing data lists and might not ever have that feature.